# Sum Values that have refer to same column

Tags: mysql, sql

My database looks like this after I do my query:

[image]

What I would like to get is the orderID with the most amount of quantities.
This is why I did to get the result from the picture:

```
SELECT orderid, quantity
From "Order"
JOIN orderitem
ON "Order".id = orderitem.orderid
JOIN product
ON orderitem.productid = product.id
```

I don't quite get how to add the values correctly to get the maximum. Happy for every help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregated function `sum` and `limit`, following query will give only one orderId with most amount of quantities.

```
SELECT orderid, sum(quantity) as quantity
From "Order"
JOIN orderitem
ON "Order".id = orderitem.orderid
JOIN product
ON orderitem.productid = product.id
group by
  orderid
order by
  quantity desc
limit 1
```